# Installation of Faiss-CPU via pip failing on Linux-Debian (armv7l)

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to install faiss-cpu with py 3.10 on a linux-armv7l machine but I recieve the error `no module named 'swig'` even tho `swig -version` returns `swig 3.0.12` (which is I believe the right version for faiss-cpu)
full traceback would be

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/bin/swig", line 5, in <module>
    from swig import swig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'swig'
error: command '/home/pi/.local/bin/swig' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you installed the `swig` python module too?

Comment: @MichaelM.
I did. I checked with "swig -version". Or what do you mean

Comment: AFAIK you need to install both swig and the `swig` python module. You can install the latter by running `pip install swig`.

Comment: @MichaelM. I don't really understand what you are talking about. I installed swig via pip with `python3.10 -m pip install swig==3.0.12`. What else do I need?